# Remove timestamp tag from a date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query comparing 2 tables, one has date in the form of "mm/dd/yyyy" (ex: 1/2/2019) but the other is "mm/dd/yyyy hh:ss:00 am/pm" (ex: 7/2/2019 8:28:00 pm")

In order for the compare to work I need to change the date with the timestamp to the form of "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: format(yourdatehere, "mm/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cut the time part:

```
Fix([DateTimeField]) = [DateField]
```

A datetime value carries no format. The format is for display only.

Answer (score 0):

```
Expr1: Format([FieldName],"mm/d/yyyy")
```

Ended up using this and it worked